# Kafka Connect internal architecture

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to understand the internal nuances of Kafka connect, like how the design has been implemented and which patterns are used.

specifically I want to understand how to develop similar app which can take input configuration and start acting according to the configuration, so when we have to implement some new feature we can just write connects. So others need not to spend more time in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: you can try following document to create custom connector
https://www.confluent.io/blog/create-dynamic-kafka-connect-source-connectors/

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka is open source, and you can find [the Connect source code here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect).

But if you just want to create a source connector, the internals will not really help you do that.

Confluent [has a blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/create-dynamic-kafka-connect-source-connectors/) on developing custom source connectors.

Alternatively, you could not "reinvent the wheel" yourself, and use projects like [Apache Camel](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/1.0.x/user-guide/index.html) to see if they support a source system you're using.